# Styling Page Control Element In UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a ViewController on my storyboard and I was wondering how I can change the selected color item in the page control via swift code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this, in your UIPageViewController subclass:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `pageIndicatorTintColor` and `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` properties.

```
self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

See [UIPageControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html) for more information.